# Rerender the page while debugging in IE9

Tags: css, debugging, internet-explorer-9

I typically debug webapps using Chrome's built in debugger. In it I can change CSS and HTML and the page will render these changes in real time. A bug in my webapp is IE specific (z-index bug) so I am using IE9's built in debugger but it does not seem to have the real time rerendering that Chrome does.

Is there a button or setting I can change to have the page update in real with my changes like it does in Chrome? Refreshing the page really isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) when working with IE.

> Compatible with all major browsers: IE6+, Firefox, Opera, Safari and
>   Chrome

Comment: "1.3. What's Not in Lite? Live editing for all panels" I don't think that would solve my problem

Comment: The new version is 1.4 and these things should now be available.